# Can't able to completely pull the branch over local and replace it

Tags: git, github

I had a branch. I ran two commands as

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>
```

I am not getting the full code that is present on github. I think that part of the code which other branches have commited and then merged into this branch , that code is not coming and getting downloaded.

I can try to just completely clone the new repository but I don't want that to do. I want to fix this only. Other SO solutions told this above thing to completely replace it but it is not happening in my case.

Comment: Is your clone a single-branch clone? What was the output of `git fetch`? (Note: never use `git fetch --all` as it does not mean what you think it means.)

Comment: As such no output was there on `git fetch`

Comment: What is the commit hash of <branch-name> in your repo? And compare that to the one on GitHub

Comment: I would guess the code you are seeing in github is on a branch different from the one you are using on the reset command.

Comment: No its the same branch.